# Custom table raw object

Tags: java, swing, jtable

As a part of a project I want to make a table with different type of object for each cell but I can't understand how to make every cell customized ... I found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) how to set a column which has a type of object like String, Bool, Slider ... but for each Cell I don't know!

This picture is from properties part of [jformDesigner](http://www.formdev.com/) software and I want something like this table :

[image]

Comment: can you also post your code for better understanding?

Comment: i use code from this website : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Asliderrendererforvolumevaluesinatable.htm

Answer (score 2):

This example might serve as a starting point:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TablePropertyEditor extends JFrame
{
    public TablePropertyEditor()
    {
        String[] columnNames = {"Type", "Value"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"String", "I'm a string"},
            {"Date", new Date()},
            {"Integer", new Integer(123)},
            {"Double", new Double(123.45)},
            {"Boolean", Boolean.TRUE}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames)
        {
            private Class editingClass;

            public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column)
            {
                editingClass = null;
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);

                if (modelColumn == 1)
                {
                    Class rowClass = getModel().getValueAt(row, modelColumn).getClass();
                    return getDefaultRenderer( rowClass );
                }
                else
                    return super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
            }

            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
            {
                editingClass = null;
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel(column);

                if (modelColumn == 1)
                {
                    editingClass = getModel().getValueAt(row, modelColumn).getClass();
                    return getDefaultEditor( editingClass );
                }
                else
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
            }

            //  This method is also invoked by the editor when the value in the editor
            //  component is saved in the TableModel. The class was saved when the
            //  editor was invoked so the proper class can be created.

            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return editingClass != null ? editingClass : super.getColumnClass(column);
            }
        };

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TablePropertyEditor frame = new TablePropertyEditor();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help ... i also want to add slider in some cell !! is it possible in this way ?

Comment: This is a simple example that would need to be expanded on. First you would need to create a "slider editor" (which I have never done). Then you would need to modify the code to use this editor. So maybe you would need a HashMap<String, TableCellEditor>. Then you would do a lookup of this table first before using basing the editor on the class.

Comment: i dont think this is the right way to do this !. as i seen in the image there is so many item customized ... may be there is a better way to do it